# How to Restrict User To View His Default POS only in odoo 8?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

How set record rules for Restrict user to view their default POS only in Odoo8 ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you can restrict a store by IP according to the docs.  like here https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/8.0/restrict_access_ip_range/

Comment: i want to create own..any way ?